# custom TreeNode and SelectNodeChanged

Tags: inheritance, treeview, treenode

I'm working on asp.net and I've written a custom TreeNode (customTreeNode) that I use to populate a TreeView.

The problem comes up when firing the selectnodechanged event which gives me a TreeNode object and not a customTreeNode. I also cannot seem to cast it.

Here is how I populate my tree:

```
 node.ChildNodes.Add
                (
                    customTreeNode = new customTreeNode(site)
                );
```

My customTreeNode class:

```
public class customTreeNode : TreeNode
    {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
        private SPWebEntry _dataContext;
        public SPWebEntry DataContext
        {
            get
            {
                return _dataContext;
            }
        }

        public customTreeNode(SPWebEntry DataContext)
        {
            _dataContext = DataContext;

            this.Text = _dataContext.Title;
            this.Id = _dataContext.Id;
        }
}
```

and the event

```
 void treeViewSiteCollection_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            treeViewSiteCollection.SelectedNode;
        }
```

`treeViewSiteCollection.SelectedNode` is of type TreeNode and I cannot cast it.

Answer (score 0):

You must extend the tree itself also
check this post
http://forums.asp.net/p/1109208/1713613.aspx#1713613